# Rotate Windows.Documents.Table

Tags: wpf, flowdocument, rotatetransform

I need to rotate a table clockwise up to 90 degrees.
It's one of the blocks of a FlowDocument.
Is there a way to apply some kind of rotation to a Table?
The possible solution of creating TextEffect like this:

```
var table = new Table();   
 ... // fill the table here
var effect = new TextEffect  
                 {
                     Transform = new RotationTransform(90),
                     PositionStart = 0,
                     PositionCount = int.MaxValue
                 };
table.TextEffects = new TextEffectCollection();
table.TextEffects.Add(effect);
```

doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved like this:
Instead of rotating table, put it into container and perform rotation on it.

```
var container = new BlockUIContainer
                          {
                              Padding = new System.Windows.Thickness(0),
                              Margin = new System.Windows.Thickness(0) 
                          };
var scrollViewer = new FlowDocumentScrollViewer
                       {
                           VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Hidden,
                           LayoutTransform = new RotateTransform(90)
                       };
container.Child = scrollViewer;
var tableDocument = new FlowDocument { PagePadding = new System.Windows.Thickness(0) };
// here the table is created
var table = operationStagesControl2.ConvertToXaml();
// adding table to document
tableDocument.Blocks.Add(table);
// hosting scroll viewer gets document
scrollViewer.Document = tableDocument;
// and in the end we have container with rotated table inside it
```